# Extract bold words from pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to export the bold words into caps of a pdf file to a text file using pdfbox library. I want to live one blank line after the word in bold. As you can see from the pdf file([Dictionary.pdf](http://www.museduc.gr/docs/gymnasio/Dictionary.pdf)) starting from page 15 its a dictionary with the definitions. The words are in bold and the definitions have normal font.

Here is how i want to my text file to look like:
"Dictionary Source:
ΑΒΑθΗΣ
ΑΒΑθΗΣ
ΑΒΑθΕΣ
ΕΠΙΘ.: όταν κάτι είναι αβαθές, δεν έχει μεγάλο βάθος (=
ρηχός, άβαθος ≠ βαθύς): Τα παιδιά μαθαίνουν
κολύμπι στα αβαθή νερά.
...."

Here is my code but unfortunately it can't separate bold from normal font. After debugging the code i realised that even if there is a bold character the text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold() is false and text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight()=0 .

```
public class PDFBoldParser extends PDFTextStripper {

    PrintWriter writer;
    boolean wasBold=false;

    public PDFBoldParser(String filepath) throws IOException{
        writer=new PrintWriter(filepath,"UTF-8");
        writer.println("Dictionary Source:");
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text){
        if(text.getFont().getFontDescriptor()!=null){
            if (text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold() ||
                    text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight() > 680 &&wasBold) {
                writer.print(text.toString().toUpperCase());
                wasBold=true;
            }
            else if(text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold() ||
                    text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight() > 680 &&!wasBold){
                writer.println();
                writer.print(text.toString().toUpperCase());
                wasBold=true;
            }
            else{
                writer.print(text.toString());
                wasBold=false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeParser(){
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could look at the font name, sometimes bold fonts have "bold" in it (but not always).

Comment: Thanks that worked for me !!!

Comment: Please answer the question yourself with your code. I'm too lazy today :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply if you replace the if statements

```
if (text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold() ||
                text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight() > 680 &&wasBold)
```

with

```
if (text.getFont().getName().contains("Bold") &&wasBold)
```

works perfectly because the Font Name for the bold text(in this situation) contains the word Bold so you can determine where a character is bold or not.